# Is this a case of an Appositive phrase? And the meaning it adds

Tags: phrase-meaning

> 'One of the tragedies of the war is that for most of the world,
> Ukraine remains the sideshow, **collateral damage in that inevitable
> drama of great power competition.'**
>
> The Indian Express,19 Feb,2023.

How does the highlighted part of the sentence connect and what is it adding to the meaning of whole sentence?

Comment: As an aside, "Is it a case of ___?" is a very non-idiomatic phrasing.  Reading that, my reaction is, "Is *what* a case of ___?" because you haven't said anything that "it" could refer to yet.  The more idiomatic phrasing is "Is **this** a case of ___?"

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for the correction.